# ActivityNotFoundException thrown in ContactManager sample

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to use the `ContactManager` from the Android developer website and when I press my button to go to the `ContactManager` it shuts down and an exception is thrown:

```
throw new ActivityNotFoundException("No Activity found to handle " + intent);
```

It is under the `switch(res)` so I am guessing that it is not connecting to the `ContactManager`. Here is my button to the `ContactManager`:

```
Button clas;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.friends);

    SettingButtons();
    clas.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.TOFRIENDS:
            startActivity(new Intent("com.clayton.calendar.ContactManager"));
            break;
    }
}

private void SettingButtons() {
    clas = (Button) findViewById(R.id.TOFRIENDS);
}
```

My `AndroidManifest` file is:

```
<activity android:name=".ContactManager" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.clayton.calendar.ContactManager" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.Default" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name="ContactAdder" android:label="@string/addContactTitle">
</activity>
```

In the `ContactManager` I changed the package to `package com.clayton.calendar` and in `AddContact` I changed the following:

```
public static final String ACCOUNT_NAME = "com.clayton.calendar.ACCOUNT_NAME";
public static final String ACCOUNT_TYPE = "com.clayton.calendar.ACCOUNT_TYPE";
```

Is there anything else in it I have to change to get it to work? I have looked through the code a few times and I don't think I've missed anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strings for the `action` and `category` elements of the `<intent-filter>` tag are case sensitive so instead of :

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.Default" />
```

use:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```